# How to initiate a job on loading a page in grails using quartz

Tags: grails, controller, action, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

I am developing a web app....I want to trigger a job as soon as a action is fired . How can this be done . I am using quartz pluggin for scheduling.

And also how can we pass data from a job to an action of controller..

Answer (score 1):

Quartz is used to trigger jobs that need to run on some kind of regular schedule, so is not really appropriate for code that needs to be run whenever a page is loaded.

If you want some code to run whenever a controller action is invoked, just put it in the action!

> how can we pass data from a job to an action of controller.

This sounds like a design flaw. Jobs should never need to invoke a controller action, I'm not even sure if it's possible.

Comment: Good answer. Maybe he wants to run the job because it contains the code he wants to execute? In that case he should factor out that code into a service that can be invoked by the controller or the job.

Comment: Just to reiterate erturne's answer. It is best practice to put the code to execute into a service that the quartz job will call. If you need to execute this from the controller, just import the service into the controller and call the same method. This makes your code DRY as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to execute the job on-demand, in the background, in addition to on a schedule, Quartz will let you do that. In your controller or service, you would just do `MyJob.triggerNow(params)` where params is a map of any arguments to the job.

The return type of `triggerNow()` is `null` so there is no easy way to get a return value from the trigger.

If you don't need the code to be executed in the background, the Job should be refactored to call a service method that can then be invoked from your controller action, like Don said.